# How to rename a session file?

Tags: php, session

I want to create and online members and guests counter. I save the members sessions in a folder and the guests sessions in another folder. I can get the number of guest simply by counting the session files, but with the members I want to get a list with the name of the members online.

Is there any way to change the session file name to the user`s name in PHP ?

Comment: you can change that in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your own session handler.

See [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) for details. There's a code sample you can easily adapt to your needs.